# EF6 Fluent API Mapping to a compound key

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5

In the following Code I am trying to tell Code First that SupplyPointServiceSubscriptions will hold 2 foreign keys. One to SupplyPoint and one to SupplyPointService.

I get error at line with *

//  Blue line under e.SupplyPoint, error :
        // Error    3   'AscendancyCF.Models.SupplyPointServiceSubscription' 
        // does not contain a definition for 'SupplyPoint' 
        //  and no extension method 'SupplyPoint' accepting a first argument of 
        // type 'AscendancyCF.Models.SupplyPointServiceSubscr.....

```
public class SupplyPointServiceSubscription
{
    [Key]
    int SupplyPointServiceSubscriptionId { get; set; }
    int? SupplyPointId { get; set; }
    int? SupplyPointServiceId { get; set; }
    DateTime SupplyPointServiceSubscriptionEffecetiveDateTime { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<SupplyPoint> SupplyPoints { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SupplyPointService> SupplyPointServices { get; set; }


}

class SupplyPointServiceSubscriptionConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<SupplyPointServiceSubscription>
{
    public SupplyPointServiceSubscriptionConfiguration()
    {   

        HasOptional(e => e.SupplyPoint).WithMany(e => e.SupplyPoints) // *
             .HasForeignKey(e => e.SupplyPointId);
        HasOptional(e => e.SupplyPointService).WithMany(e => e.SupplyPointServices) // * and here
             .HasForeignKey(e => e.SupplyPointServiceId);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not possible. See answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9081419/60108

Comment: Eranga when I try the suggestion I get an error, many thanks in advance